# What is $E[1/X]$ for $f(x) = 3x^2$ when $0<x<1$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Given a pdf of $f(x) = 3x^2$ for  $0 < x < 1$ or $f(x)=0$ otherwise, how to find $E[1/X]$?

I followed the formula:

($E[1/x] = \int f(x) (1/x) dx$

and I got a result of $3/2$ or $1.5$, which is outside of the support. Because it's outside of the support does that mean that my answer is wrong?

Comment: No. Your "result" is 3/2, but remember that the result you calculated is for 1/X, not X. Because the support of X is (0,1), the support for $1/X$ is $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Is there any result that says the expected value of $g(X)$ has to be within the support of $X$ for any function $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not actually, think that the support $(0,1)$ corresponds to the random variable $X$, since your are considering a function $g(X)=1/X$ the expected value will be, as you said, 
$$\int f_X(x)g(x)dx$$